# How can I Implement Adaptive merge sort in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop

I have written adaptive merge sort in java. But as a mapreduce program there are three class . one is map , two is reducer and third is driver . I am not understaing how to convert this code to mapreduce so that I can run this on hadoop multi node cluster?

here is the code :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
        MainClass.SortClass sortClass = mainClass.new SortClass();
        sortClass.sortMainFunction();
    }

    public class Constant {
        public static final int MAX = 10000;
        public static final int max = 10000;
    }

    public class Values {
        int st_index;
        int ed_index;
        boolean as_ds;

        public Values(int st_index, int ed_index, boolean as_ds) {
            this.st_index = st_index;
            this.ed_index = ed_index;
            this.as_ds = as_ds;
        }
    }

    public class SortClass {
        int[] a = new int[Constant.MAX];
        int[] b = new int[Constant.MAX];
        int index1 = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int numberOfItem = 0, first_ind, end_ind, tem, k, g, h;
        boolean flag;
        Values node[] = new Values[Constant.max];
        int p, q, r, low, high, j;

        void insert(int st_ind, int end_ind, boolean fl) {


            node[index1] = new Values(st_ind, end_ind, fl);
            index1++;
        }

        public void sortMainFunction() throws Exception {
            addDataIntoArray();

            first_ind = 0;
            end_ind = 0;
            flag = false;
            tem = a[0];
            k = 1;

            while (true) {

                while (true) {
                    if (k < i && tem >= a[k]) {
                        end_ind = k;
                        tem = a[k];
                        k++;
                        flag = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (flag) {



                    node[index1] = new Values(first_ind, end_ind, flag);
                    index1++;


                    first_ind = k;
                    end_ind = k;
                    if (k >= i) {

                    } else {
                        tem = a[k++];
                    }

                }

                while (true) {
                    if (k < i && tem <= a[k]) {
                        tem = a[k];
                        end_ind = k;
                        flag = false;
                        k++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (!flag) {
                    insert(first_ind, end_ind, flag);
                    first_ind = end_ind = k;
                    if (k >= i) {

                    } else {
                        tem = a[k++];
                    }

                }

                if (end_ind == i)
                    break;
            }

            g = index1 - 1;
            h = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (g / 2 <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                g /= 2;
                h++;
            }

            System.out.println(h);
            h = (int) ((double) Math.log((double) index1 - 1) / (double) Math.log(2.0));
            System.out.println(h);

            p = 1;
            for (q = 0; q <= h; q++, p *= 2) {
                for (r = 0; r < index1; r++) {
                    if (2 * r * p + p >= index1)
                        break;
                    else {
                        low = 2 * p * r;
                        high = 2 * p * r + p;
                        k = node[low].st_index;
                        if (node[low].as_ds == false && node[high].as_ds == false) {
                            i = node[low].st_index;
                            j = node[high].st_index;

                            while (i <= node[low].ed_index && j <= node[high].ed_index) {
                                if (a[i] <= a[j])
                                    b[k++] = a[i++];
                                else
                                    b[k++] = a[j++];
                            }
                            if (i > node[low].ed_index)
                                while (j <= node[high].ed_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[j++];
                            else
                                while (i <= node[low].ed_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[i++];
                        } else if (node[low].as_ds == false && node[high].as_ds == true) {
                            i = node[low].st_index;
                            j = node[high].ed_index;

                            while (i <= node[low].ed_index && j >= node[high].st_index) {
                                if (a[i] <= a[j])
                                    b[k++] = a[i++];
                                else
                                    b[k++] = a[j--];
                            }
                            if (i > node[low].ed_index)
                                while (j >= node[high].st_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[j--];
                            else
                                while (i <= node[low].ed_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[i++];
                        } else if (node[low].as_ds == true && node[high].as_ds == false) {
                            i = node[low].ed_index;
                            j = node[high].st_index;

                            while (i >= node[low].st_index && j <= node[high].ed_index) {
                                if (a[i] <= a[j])
                                    b[k++] = a[i--];
                                else
                                    b[k++] = a[j++];
                            }
                            if (j > node[high].ed_index)
                                while (i >= node[low].st_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[i--];
                            else
                                while (j <= node[high].ed_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[j++];
                        } else if (node[low].as_ds == true && node[high].as_ds == true) {
                            i = node[low].ed_index;
                            j = node[high].ed_index;

                            while (i >= node[low].st_index && j >= node[high].st_index) {
                                if (a[i] <= a[j])
                                    b[k++] = a[i--];
                                else
                                    b[k++] = a[j--];
                            }
                            if (i < node[low].st_index)
                                while (j >= node[high].st_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[j--];
                            else
                                while (i >= node[low].st_index)
                                    b[k++] = a[i--];
                        }
                        for (k = node[low].st_index; k <= node[high].ed_index; k++)
                            a[k] = b[k];

                        node[low].ed_index = node[high].ed_index;
                        node[high].st_index = node[low].st_index;
                        node[low].as_ds = false;
                        node[high].as_ds = false;
                    }
                }
            }



            BufferedWriter output = null;

            File file = new File("output.txt");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            for (k = 0; k < numberOfItem; k++) {
                String s = String.valueOf(a[k]);
                output.write(s);
                output.newLine();
            }

            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }



        }

        public void addDataInt

    oArray() throws Exception {
                Scanner scanner;
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    i++;
                    numberOfItem++;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That is not merge sort. Merge sort uses tons recursion and is far shorter. I would be surprised if this ran any faster than bubble sort. This is asking far too much of stackoverflow. Try to do this yourself, and then come to us with what you have tried. Meanwhile, read up on your sorts!

Comment: yeah this is not merge sort. Read the title . This is adaptive Merge Sort . Or if u don't know abut Adaptive Merge Sort then google it . Adaptive Merge Sort is much faster then Merge sort .

Comment: I apologize then, but it is still asking too much of stack overflow.

Comment: I am sorry too if I m asking too much . Actually as I have understood well the wordcount example that it consist of 3 class . 1 is map 2 is reduce and 3 is driver and also in map the text is converted into token . But I have not got a single example that explain sorting well . Like in sorting how many classes are required and also how to deal with the integers. I have studied and come to know that in mapreduce map does the sorting so if I want to specify any sorting then It needs to secondary sorting. But I am not understanding how the secondary sorting can be done.

Comment: After reading about adaptive merge sort, its downside is more memory usage. That nullifies any big o difference and it has the same worst case big o as merge sort either way. I think I would stick with regular merge sort unless you know that what you are doing is definitively the perfect case to use adaptive merge sort. Merge sort is far easier to read, and therefore it is far better for 99% of circumstances for that reason alone.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a7b/b7d936abc2b69d1fed190ac6589f0d006603.pdf

Comment: 2010... computers weren't nearly as fast on average then. Every year readability becomes more important as that's what allows code to scale indefinitely. As of now, readability is #1 most important thing in code by far. I'm not saying performance doesn't have its moments of necessity, but they are few and far between. Are you needing to use this sort on a moments notice millions of times a day? If not, then likely readability is more important.